# Compare path directories to dictionary and retreive key from dictionary for a match

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary with a numeric value for key and a directory path for value.

I am trying to iterate through a folder (which also has subfolders) and create two columns for an RDS table:  1) file name, 2) numeric value of folder path for that file (folder path ID)

When trying to loop through the foler and its subfolders, I get repeated values. I think when there are subfolders it loops over and over for each subfolder and I get duplicate entries for files and their associated folder path ID.

This is a snippet of code for response['Content']:

```
{'ETag': '"0c7a50851d188f2d3b112a1f338b8c36"',
  'Key': 'Repos/TEMPLATE/Name/IRB/8-Recruitment '
         'Materials/path8.sh',
  'LastModified': '2019-05-23T23:18:16+00:00',
  'Owner': {'DisplayName': 'user001',
            'ID': '024ea7e7ee4dee8da7a426dbc2105e8f577f476d676d229473d96e7a0e63d274'},
  'Size': 50,
  'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'},
 {'ETag': '"0c7a50851d188f2d3b112a1f338b8c36"',
  'Key': 'Repos/TEMPLATE/Name/Reg. 1/1-Memos to File/Old '
         'Memos/path9.sh',
  'LastModified': '2019-05-23T23:18:16+00:00',
  'Owner': {'DisplayName': 'user001',
            'ID': '024ea7e7ee4dee8da7a426dbc2105e8f577f476d676d229473d96e7a0e63d274'},
  'Size': 50,
  'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'},
 {'ETag': '"0c7a50851d188f2d3b112a1f338b8c36"',
  'Key': 'Repos/TEMPLATE/Group Name/Reg. 1/Misc/path18.sh',
  'LastModified': '2019-05-23T23:18:16+00:00',
  'Owner': {'DisplayName': 'user001',
            'ID': '024ea7e7ee4dee8da7a426dbc2105e8f577f476d676d229473d96e7a0e63d274'}
```

DIRECTORIES is a dictionary like this:

```
13: 'Repos/TEMPLATE/Name/Reg. 1/1-Memos to File/Old', 
14: 'Repos/TEMPLATE/Name/Reg. 1/1-Memos to File/Misc',
```

OUTPUT should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO document.Document(documentName,folderID,repositoryID,recCreatedByUserID) 
    VALUES("path19.sh",13,1,35);
```

Below is the code that I am trying to get to work. The values that are generated seems to be correct, but how do I get rid of the duplicated iterations?

```
for file in response['Contents']:
    for k,v in directories.items():
        if os.path.dirname(file['Key']) in v:
            print(
                'INSERT INTO document.Document(documentName,folderID,repositoryID,recCreatedByUserID)',
                "\n",
               'VALUES("{}",{},1,{});'.format(os.path.basename(file['Key']),k,randint(1, 40)))
```

This is being used in combination with boto3 like this:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('tes0001-2019052325451')
result = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket.name,
                                     Delimiter="/*")
```

to get the contents of an S3 bucket. Theoretically, this code should work with any bucket.

---

PROBLEM SUMMARY: 
I've been able to narrow down the behavior to this:

For each subfolder within a root folder, python is looping through the subfolders -1. IF there are 5 subfolders, I am getting the output of all 5 subfolders, then of the 4 subfolders again, then 3, 2, 1.

I have a folder structure like this:

```
  FolderA
    |-FolderB
    |   |-File1
    |-FolderC
    |   |-File2
    |-FolderD
    |   |-File3
    |-FolderE
    |   |-File4
```

I am getting the following output:

```
A/B/1
A/C/2
A/D/3
A/E/4
A/C/2
A/D/3
A/E/4
A/D/3
A/E/4
A/E/4
```

Regardless of how many subfolders are in a folder, I only need to loop through all the contents once. Not keep looping with on less folder until no more folders.

Comment: Please add your current output and desired output (not in words but in a format we can replicate) and add the contents of `response['Contents']`.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I added more content. The current output and desired output is the same and is the correct output. The only problem is there are extra records. I didn't include the entire content of response as that would be over 1000 lines of code. Hope this is enough information.

Comment: Which records are the "extra" records? Sorry just trying to figure out whats what :P

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I added a "PROBLEM SUMMARY" for a high-level overview of what I see happening. I think this is just a general problem with FOR loop. I'm looping over content more times than needed. It looks like what is happening is that if there are 5 subfolders in a root folder, I loop through the root folder 5 times. This problem is compounded if a subfolder has subfolders and so on. The list of files becomes very large with mostly redundant content.

Comment: When I get near a computer in a few days I can help find a fix.  Well detailed question though.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Thanks a lot for taking a look. I was able to use os.walk method as described here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm. Copying the example and replacing "." with the root directory path generates a list of all files with path in the folder structure as one would want and expect.